# Closing the first form in C# to show the second, but after closing the second the first comes back

Tags: c#, forms, instantiation

So far, this is the button click event to instantiate the other form of the button. It pops up the other form—but the first form is still in the background, and after closing the second one, the first also closes and stops running. Any advice?

```
private void BtnInventoryClickEvent(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        frmInv viewInve = new frmInv();
        viewInve.ShowDialog();
        this.Hide();
    }
```

Comment: You're not closing the form, but you can call this.Hide() before viewInve.ShowDialog();

Comment: Try following :  this.Visiable = false; viewInve.Show();
        this.Visible = true;

Comment: Be aware of the parent control element of both forms. Here you control the child forms behaviour (which are opened and shown). So, if you open a form, you need to hide or close all other opend/shown forms in this parent control element. That means, if you want to replace an existing child form you need to use a public function inside the parent form which handles this and which can be called when clicking on your child forms button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code seems to (unintentionally) stop at the  .ShowDialog() line:

```
// your first line:
        frmInv viewInve = new frmInv(); // here the new frmInv is getting created successfully
        viewInve.ShowDialog(); // but here the code would stop
// because ShowDialog() produces a so called "modal window", AKA "dialog"
// so that the next line does not run before the current user would 
// interactively close frmInv.
// And then the next line hides your current Form:
        this.Hide();
```